# Устаревшая картинка на странице удаления профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, справка

*В связи с продолжающимися просьбами одного из участников, решил посмотреть сам, как же участник может удалить свой профиль?*

- На странице справки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account устаревшая информация (скрин со старой версии SO).

Мелочь, но хорошо бы обновить

Comment: Нарушаются права участников на виртуальное харакири! Модераторов на мыло!

Comment: Собственно повод http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484252

Comment: ну и, как успехи, сообщества? такой сложный вопрос? может, конкурс открыть?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484252/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82?noredirect=1#comment561004_484252
и
meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2362/Устаревшая-картинка-на-странице-удаления-профиля.
модераторы сайт не знают.
интерес, это искренне написано:
Хорошо, раз у вас не получается, то я удалю вашу учетную запись. Сожалею что в этот раз мы друг друга не поняли, и надеюсь, что вы когда-нибудь вернётесь. Через 24 часа ваша учетная запись будет удалена (быстрее не могу, таковы ограничения системы). – Nick Volynkin

Comment: @айтишник: да, искренне. Я не пишу ложно, зачем бы. Что мы не удаляли свои учётки — логично, их мало кто удаляет.